# Flutter error: E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documenFailed to handle message

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to do a simple firestore reading from my app and getting this error:

```
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documenFailed to handle message
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documenjava.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.GeneratedAndroidFirebaseFirestore$PigeonDocumentOption.fromList(GeneratedAndroidFirebaseFirestore.java:934)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.GeneratedAndroidFirebaseFirestore$FirebaseFirestoreHostApiCodec.readValueOfType(GeneratedAndroidFirebaseFirestore.java:1433)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.readValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:340)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.readValueOfType(StandardMessageCodec.java:424)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.FlutterFirebaseFirestoreMessageCodec.readValueOfType(FlutterFirebaseFirestoreMessageCodec.java:284)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore.GeneratedAndroidFirebaseFirestore$FirebaseFirestoreHostApiCodec.readValueOfType(GeneratedAndroidFirebaseFirestore.java:1449)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.readValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:340)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.decodeMessage(StandardMessageCodec.java:89)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at io.flutter.plugin.common.BasicMessageChannel$IncomingMessageHandler.onMessage(BasicMessageChannel.java:262)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:292)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documen    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

My flutter doctor output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 3.19.0-0.1.pre, on macOS 14.2.1 23C71 darwin-arm64, locale pt-BR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] Network resources
```

My packages:

```
cloud_firestore: ^4.14.0
cloud_functions: ^4.6.0
firebase_auth: ^4.16.0
firebase_core: ^2.24.2
```

The code:

```
DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("app").doc("info").get();
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: I would like to see the JSON that your query returns because I think you are trying to use a string where it should be a boolean. I mean, the server returns this to you:

```json
{
  "valid_user": true
}
```

And you might be validating something like this:

```json
{
  "valid_user": "true"
}
```

Comment: This is the data: `{"version_ios": ["1.1.5"],"version": ["1.1.5"],"version_android": ["1.1.5","1.1.6"]}`

Comment: Then check if you are doing any validation with that data and comparing a string with some boolean result, that is true or false because the error as I see in what you show is that. 
 **E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.cloud_firestore_platform_interface.FirebaseFirestoreHostApi.documenjava.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean**

Comment: I was just printing the `doc` variable, without doing any kind of check. But I realized that I had recently updated Flutter, and by downgrading to version `v3.18.0-0.2.pre` everything worked normally again.